# Extending vector grid over larger region using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, vector-grid

I have a polygon grid (as a shapefile) over a certain portion of the United States.  Each cell is 500 square miles, and there is a specific projection, etc associated with the grid.  I want to extend the same grid, with the same cell resolution, size, etc to cover a larger portion of the country.

How do I do this?

I have tried the trim/extend tool, but that does not seem to work, unless I am doing something wrong.  I would really like to just extend the current grid to keep the exact same properties, rather than attempting to recreate it.

Comment: You can copy/paste specific features and move them to the correct location perhaps? To recreate it, but bigger, have you tried the Create Fishnet tool? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/how-create-fishnet-works.htm

Comment: I have tried it, but i can't replicate the grid for some reason.